# $pull array embedded docs MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

this is my problem, I need to remove a specific _id charge reference into array members.charges from specific member.id into a embedded doc.

(I hope be clear about my issue).

I try with this.

---

```
db.branches.update(

    {'members._id':ObjectId("565dc20d338b60720c25e8d0"),
     'members.charges':  ObjectId("565dc20d338b60720c25e8d1")  
    },
    {
        $pull:{'members.charges': ObjectId("565dc20d338b60720c25e8d1")  }   
    }
);
```

(branches, is the name of the collection).

---

But mongoDB says:

cannot use the part (members of members.charges) to traverse the element.

---

My collection structure is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565dc1cb338b60720c25e8ce"),

    "phone" : "33 2132 1321",
    "address" : "whereever",
    "name" : "Gym2",
    "account_id" : ObjectId("565dc1ad338b60720c25e8cc"),
    "visits" : [],
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Test User",
            "package" : ObjectId("565dc1f9338b60720c25e8cf"),
            "address" : "Sur 113 A No 429",
            "phone" : "32 1321 3232",
            "contactPhone" : "32 3213 1231",
            "email" : "test@gmail.com",
            "pendingCharges" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("565dc20d338b60720c25e8d0"),
            "created" : ISODate("2015-12-01T15:51:41.187Z"),
            "charges" : [ 
                ObjectId("565dc20d338b60720c25e8d1")
            ],
            "active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Test user 2",
            "package" : ObjectId("565dc1f9338b60720c25e8cf"),
            "address" : "whereever",
            "phone" : "32 1321 3232",
            "contactPhone" : "32 3213 1231",
            "email" : "uodsaanduco@gmail.com",
            "pendingCharges" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("565dc22b338b60720c25e8d2"),
            "created" : ISODate("2015-12-01T15:52:11.581Z"),
            "charges" : [ 
                ObjectId("565dc22b338b60720c25e8d3")
            ],
            "active" : true
        }
    ],
    "packages" : [ 
        ObjectId("565dc1f9338b60720c25e8cf")
    ]
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the update which `members` array element to look in when pulling the `charges` element. You can do that with the [positional `$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator that represents the index of the matched `members` array element from the query:

```
db.branches.update(

    {'members._id':ObjectId("565dc20d338b60720c25e8d0"),
     'members.charges':  ObjectId("565dc20d338b60720c25e8d1")  
    },
    {
        $pull:{'members.$.charges': ObjectId("565dc20d338b60720c25e8d1")  }   
    }
);
```